# Scribe Jobs: how to get the current date and compare it?

Tags: jobs, scribe-workbench

Honesty I'm very new in terms of Scribe Jobs, but I have been trying to develop a Job that get the current date and compare it against one field from the source (CRM input Date).

This is the code in the formula editor of the Pre-Operation Step Control:

`IF(S146 =TODAY( ), GOTOSTEP ( ),FAILROW( ))`

I'm trying to allow the migration only for records inserted today, the rest will just generate error.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if( DATEDIFF ("d", GETCURRENTUTCTIME, S146) < 1 )
```

Here's a great place to look for more information:
http://help.scribesoft.com/scribeonline/en/sol/formulas/datefunctions.htm